# PHPMailer is changing my SMTP Host to my hostname, causing it to fail

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to use gmails SMTP servers to send with. There is a fairly clear example included in PHPMailer for this exact scenario, but after following it I'm getting an error because (it looks to me like) the host has changed to my local hostname after specifying it?

Error:

```
Peer certificate CN=`myhostname' did not match expected CN=`smtp.gmail.com' 
[/app/versions/dev/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php line 389]
```

Code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPOptions = [
  'ssl' => [
    'verify_peer' => false,
    // 'verify_peer_name' => false,
    // 'allow_self_signed' => true
  ]
];
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'mygmail@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'mypass';
$mail->AddAddress('mygmail@gmail.com', 'My Name');
$mail->Subject = 'subject';
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
echo $mail->send();
exit;
```

I can see in PHPMailer.php:1772 that it falls back to serverHostname() if $Helo isn't specified, but when I look at $Helo's docblock, it refers to $Hostname which doesn't exist.

---

myhostname, mygmail@gmail.com, mypass are all anonymised by the way.

Comment: try removing your `$mail->SMTPOptions`

Comment: @cmorrissey it fails without `ssl->verify_peer = false` and gives me loads of broken characters, not even a real error mesage. I've read its a certificate error but it's not one I can fix as this is local, so the only other (unrecommended) workaround is adding that.

Comment: ahhhh actually if you look at the gmail example https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps i think you need to use `$mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');` instead of your host line i don't think your network is allowing SMTP over IPv6

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to change too if the SMTP mail route to yourdomain, you need to set too your PHP application by changing the php.ini smtp domain.

```
 //php.ini
 [mail function]
 ; For Win32 only.
 ; http://php.net/smtp
 SMTP = smtp.yourdomain.com
```

At the top of your php program where the program start loader constructor you need to add this tiny code :

```
//php index contructor loader ...
ini_set("SMTP","smtp.example.com" );
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'user@example.com');
```

Regards

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu so I don't think those options are relevant, and it shows a different hostname anyway :P thanks though

Comment: I am from debian no mutch different. https://www.smtp2go.com/setupguide/php_mailer/ may be you didn't see the first caracter ; is a comment

Comment: under php.ini the ";" is for comment only, this no a line that being executed.

Comment: this example came to my copy paste but in your way go to https://askubuntu.com/questions/356968/find-the-correct-php-ini-file to set it or use the ini_set into the PHP page

Answer (score -1):

This is not something that PHPMailer is doing. Read what the error says: you're asking to connect to `smtp.gmail.com`, but ending up connecting to something else, so the certificate name doesn't match. This is presumably because your ISP is intercepting your SMTP traffic and redirecting it to their own mail server, which has a different name – this is very common. It's nothing to do with the `Hostname` property.

This is *exactly why* you check certificates - what they are doing is a man-in-the-middle attack, and is one of the things that TLS protects you against, so disabling the checks is absolutely the wrong thing to do, and it also means you have handed over your gmail credentials to your ISP, so you may want to change your gmail password.

The right solution is to find out from your ISP what arrangements they want you to use for outbound email (presumably using their mail server), and alter your script to use that deliberately, rather than accidentally, and then the certificate name will match.

You'll then have a different problem - most ISPs like google and particularly Yahoo, have SPF records set that will mark mail originating from outside their network that says it was sent by them as invalid and will probably end up blocked by recipients.

The solution to that is to send using a From address at your ISP, rather than gmail.

The best solution is to use an ISP that doesn't block your traffic.

Comment: I think this may be my work network blocking it rather than the ISP, but that's a good start for me anyway